# How this strange traffic from Samara, Russia works?

Tags: .htaccess, google-analytics, spam, traffic

I just put up a new website. New domain, new everything. I set up Google Analytics and my first ever visitor is this:

forum.topic60670121.darodar.com (i do not linking it, it is spam)

I know lot of people experience traffic from several Russian spam sites those redirect to some other site. I read a lot of about it. I can't ban them even from htaccess like this:

```
## SITE REFERRER BANNING
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} semalt.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} Darodar.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} Priceg.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} 7makemoneyonline.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} Buttons-for-website.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} Ilovevitaly.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} Blackhatworth.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} Econom.co [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} Iskalko.ru [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} Lomb.co [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} Lombia.co [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} hulfingtonpost.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} cenoval.ru [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} o-o-6-o-o.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} humanorightswatch.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} bestwebsitesawards.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

deny from 78.110.60.230
deny from 217.23.11.15
deny from 217.23.7.180
deny from 217.23.8.124
```

It just doesn't work. And I given up on this at another website. But the question is:

**How it is possible they visit a site that is so new even I barely know about it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why you get the traffic at all**

This [blog post](http://egenie.biz/russian-spam-traffic-from-darodar-com-co-lumb/) might be an actual explanation for your question: The author of the blog post finds evidence that the spammers harvest Google Analytics UA codes to artificially send page hits. The link in your GA reports should then contain a referral identifier.
The author suspects that UA codes may also be auto-generated.

**Other possible causes for it happening so quickly**

Have you entered the domain name into a webservice tool to test something? E.g. DNS setup, SEO tools, or similar? They might have been breached and do not know about it. I experience such weird traffic on my domains, too and have begun to ignore them.

**How to get rid of the weird traffic in your reports**

You can also setup your reports in GA to exclude those from the numbers being reported (unless you are also actively targeting the area where the weird traffic originates). There is a great blog post explaining how to [filter bad traffic from GA](http://www.jeffalytics.com/8-steps-eliminating-bad-data-google-analytics/). The blog post also states darodar.com as their traffic source.

Comment: I just put it to google's webmaster's tool and analytics. Non other place. I just started to set up all these but after 10 minutes I got the first russian visitor like this.

Comment: I have just restructured the answer and included another link that may indeed explain why you get such traffic.

Comment: So this is why they were on my site before real people.

Answer (score 1):

> How it is possible they visit a site that is so new even I barely know about it?

They don't visit your site. They send data directly to Google Analytics and leverage the fact that by picking property IDs randomly, there is a significant probability to hit existing Web properties.

For more background information and a discussion about different approaches to eliminate referrer spam:

http://veithen.github.io/2015/01/21/referrer-spam.html